# How do i exlude Domain class from getting exported in a grails plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a plugin that i have created, and in that plugin i have a TestDomain domain class which is just used in an integration test. How can i exlude TestDomain from being exported to grails projects using my plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add it to the `pluginExcludes` list:

```
def pluginExcludes = [
   'grails-app/domain/com/foo/TestDomain'
]
```